# Highlight same nth-child element

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Suppose I have the following table:

```
+----------+
| A  |  B  |
+----------+
| 1  |  2  |
+----------+
```

I want to make so that when I hover over `A` that `1` gets certain css styles, ditto for `B` and `2`. Is there a way to do this without using js?

### [Here's a fiddle to see what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/en5rB/)

Comment: Do you want the 1 to get the same style as A when A is hovered, and the same with B-2?

Comment: Can the data be built by column? Using a div per column could use hover to apply to the column. Visually it could be designed to look exactly the same.

Comment: @JTSmith: yeah same rules for `A-1` and `B-2`

Comment: @DustinGraham: I'd rather not do it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this markup and pure CSS it's not possible because you would need to use `td:hover` to apply the CSS rule  on mouseover, and there is no selector that lets you travel up the DOM tree (which would be necessary as you want to target cells that live in a different branch from the one being hovered).

If you can modify then a solution such as Dustin's can work; if you can use JS then it's also a matter of [sprinkling a little jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/UznED/) on the table:

```
$("td").on("mouseenter mouseout", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("table").find("td:nth-child(" + ($this.index() + 1) + ")")
                          .toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: You can change `mouseenter mouseout` to just `hover`

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the markup, here's a response jsfiddle to do this with CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/dBrd2/

Edit: Ah, but I see you replied to my comment and said you didn't want to. Anyways, just an idea if you reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class called .hover, and do like this for adding the style to all the td's with the same class

```
$("td.fir").bind("mouseenter", function(){
   $(".fir").addClass("hover");
});​​​​
$("td.fir").bind("mouseleave", function(){
   $(".fir").removeClass("hover");
});
```

​

Comment: Is this "a way to do this without using JS"?

Comment: I've tried to do it with css3 transitions, but you cannot do like you do with jquery, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do as like this

**Css**

```
td {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 50px;
}


tr .fir{
    background:red;
}
table:hover .fir{
    background:green;
}



​
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="fir">a</td>
    <td class="sec">b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fir">1</td>
    <td class="sec">2</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Live Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/en5rB/3/